# Why does looking at a dtsx file modify it?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, ssis

I'm looking of a DTSX file that I didn't make, trying to get an overview of how it works. But I've noticed that every time I open up an Execute SQL Task or File System Task it checks out the dtsx from TFS. I haven't changed anything, so why does it always check out the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the dtsx file is overly burdensome and mixes UI and data/programming elements in the same backing file? *winces*

Without seeing the specific file, what I had noticed back when I used version control systems that subscribed to the checkout/modify/checkin pattern is that things such as package configuration, expressions, etc may get re-evaluated as you open tasks which I assume the TFS modify daemon in VS detects the file could get dirty and so checks it out to help you.

You'll also notice that if you run the package, sometimes it gets checked out and marked as modified. Which is totally fun as you get to play: what was I doing before I left my desk? Did I actually make a change or was I just looking?

Not helping matters is that the save action from visual studio always triggers two changes: version build (which is a monotonically increasing number) and the corresponding version guid.

Not an answer, but I can commiserate with your experience. The answer likely lies in the engineering minds in Redmond and was never publicly documented.

Comment: Probably better it was never documented, who knows what Lovecraftian horrors lurk in the minds at Redmond, better for our own sanity that we never know.